Flutter VLC player causing crash with slow network
I have a problem with using flutter_vlc_player, I am doing an app that has tv channels listed in a page and plays them using vlc player, it is not working badly on good networks, however, on bad networks, like 3g networks in my country. I get a lot of crashes if I keep going from channel to channel, the reason being Flutter main thread being blocked.
I tried another player called video_player but it doesn't work well with my links, and another player called FijkPlayer, it works nicely on Android and loads live channels without crashing once on 3g or fast networks, however, it crashes on Android 9,10 and some channel's audio isn't working on IOS. There's another recommended package called better_player which is built upon video_player so that won't work either and it conflicts with another important package I have.
So, I am out of options and resort to using vlc player for IOS and android 9,10. I initialize it in initState.
vlcPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.network(widget.url,
        hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoInitialize: true,
        options: VlcPlayerOptions(
          extras: [':adaptive-use-access', ],
          http: VlcHttpOptions([
            VlcHttpOptions.httpUserAgent(dotenv.env['streamer_user_agent'] ?? ''),
            VlcHttpOptions.httpReconnect(true),
          ]),
          rtp: VlcRtpOptions([
            VlcRtpOptions.rtpOverRtsp(true),
          ]),
          advanced: VlcAdvancedOptions([
            VlcAdvancedOptions.networkCaching(2000),
          ]),
        ));
    ```

I want to know if there are any additional options I can try to make it work asynchronously or stream live channels smoothly without lagging the entire UI on weak networks.

P.S I use https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/ to find options.

